# How to make selenium detect when user is done a captcha?

Tags: java, selenium, bots, recaptcha, captcha

(Java) I am currently automating something for a website. The website has a captcha which the user has to solve themselves. How would I get Selenium to detect when the user correctly finishes the captcha? The HTML for the captcha is:

```
<iframe title="recaptcha challenge" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&amp;v=qc5B-qjP0QEimFYUxcpWJy5B&amp;k=6LdGX9YZAAAAAJLVmkBk-ftvS9rTtn-hmJ8sK0pb&amp;cb=u5hii8bi5hjp" name="c-pfcx4jwb7hud" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" style="width: 400px; height: 580px;"></iframe>
```

After looking at the HTML code, everytime I open up the captcha the visibilty in the code changes from hidden to visible, how would I detect if the captcha is hidden or visible.

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 2px 2px 3px; position: absolute; transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear 0s; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; z-index: 2000000000; left: 233px; top: -10000px;
```

After further analysis this is the HTML code that determines if the captcha box is checked or not

```
class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-checked rc-anchor-checkbox"
```

How would I cause selenium to read this line?

Comment: May be you can check for the iframe presence once it is solve it will disappears mostly and if same happens in your case

Comment: I edited the post, can you explain to me how selenium would read that class?